Quickfix/N How to recover from 'Lower sequence received than expected without PossDup flag.' error
I have a setup depicted in the picture below to read dropcopy messages.

Here is the config file:
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=2
FileStorePath=store
StartTime=06:00:00
EndTime=20:30:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
AppDataDictionary=FIX50SP2.xml
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
SocketIgnoreProxy=Y
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
FileLogPath=log
ScreenLogShowIncoming=N
ScreenLogShowOutgoing=N
ScreenLogShowEvents=N
LogoutTimeout=5
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
CheckLatency=N
SenderCompID=src_comp
TargetCompID=target_comp
HeartBtInt=30
BeginString=FIXT.1.1



[SESSION]
SessionQualifier=SESSION1
SocketConnectHost=….
SocketConnectPort=1234
Username=xxx
Password=xxx
SenderSubID=abcd

My questions are:

"Reader" app crashed for some reason during the day, I noticed and restarted but started getting the error below:

20240726-09:29:56.182 : 8=FIXT.1.19=00015335=549=BI56=BIIYF34=10822252=20240726-09:29:56.1811409=458=Lower sequence received than expected without PossDup flag. Expected/Received = 177/17510=159.

What is the proper way to recover from this state? Should I restart the app after deleting log/ and store/ folders or is there a better way?

Also I get the error below but I mitigated it by defining "CheckLatency=N" in the config

Message 344443 Rejected: 10
20240729-14:24:04.453 : Sending time accuracy problem


I assigned N to all Reset* flags. I wrote a script which stops and starts the app in the morning and evening and delete log/ and store/ folders. IS this good in your opinion?

